# Android:access to row view of standard listview in code

Tags: android, android-listview

I've created a Listview simple, with ArrayAdapter using ArrayList filled of Strings. I used the standard layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1.
I need, from code, to change the background color from a row, knowing its position, but not using onClick event (in this case the event give me the view). 
I need "extract" the View (of Row) from this Listview in a position specific and last, change the background.

I've used:

```
int position = 13; //example
View v = listaParrafos.getChildAt(position);
if (v != null)
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

it works in little lists.

My problem is that my ListView has 133 rows, and "getChildAt(position)" use position from visible rows, not from all ListView. 
For example, if I've in my screen, the rows between positions 10 and 20 of listview, if I use listaParrafos.getChildAt(0); return me the view from real position 10 in listview.

I need return the real view from position to change the background. How I can to do that?

Comment: If you're smart you're recycling views in your `ListView`.  This means that any list item that isn't currently visible doesn't have a view.  So you'll need to develop a strategy for tracking what background color you want to use for each view when that view becomes visible and set the background at that time.

Comment: How I can to know whose positions from listview I'm showing? there's some method or I need to compare in row content to infer this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're smart you're recycling views in your ListView. This means that any list item that isn't currently visible doesn't have a view. So you'll need to develop a strategy for tracking what background color you want to use for each view when that view becomes visible and set the background at that time.

There are ways to get the positions of the visible views from your `ListView` ([#getFirstVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29), [#getLastVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29)), however this is not necessary. Re-read what I said above.

Develop a strategy for tracking what background color you want to use for each item (view when that view becomes visible) and set the background at that time (when your adapter's `getView()` is called.

As a very simple example, let's say you add an array of ints (resource ids) to your `ArrayAdapter` in order to track the background color you want to use for each item.  You might initialize the array to contain the default background color in your constructor, provide a method for updating the color that is associated with a string in the list, and in your `getView`, just set the background to the corresponding color.